# How to add the same value to a datatable from excel?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

```
    private void btnSelectFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    }
    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = txtfilepath.Text;

        string ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";
        DataTable Data = new DataTable();

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [Inventory List (HK)$]", conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(Data);

            conn.Close();
        }
        string ConnStr = MyConString;
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBC = new SqlBulkCopy(ConnStr))
        {
            sqlBC.DestinationTableName = "dbo.InventoryList";
            sqlBC.ColumnMappings.Add("User ID", "username");
            sqlBC.ColumnMappings.Add("User Name", "username");
            sqlBC.ColumnMappings.Add("Remarks", "remarks");

            sqlBC.WriteToServer(Data);
        }


        Data.Columns.Add("InventoryListType", typeof(System.String));

        foreach (DataRow row in Data.Rows)
        {


            row["InventoryListType"] = "HK";   
        }
        MessageBox.Show("UPLOAD SUCCESSFULLY");
    }
}
```

}

I build a windows Forms Application with 3  buttons and I already have a column name call InventoryListType in my datatable, I want to **add a value "HK"** in **every row** in *sheet* Inventory List and in *column* InventoryListType, but I cannot do this and my code is above. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri I can upload the excel information in a data table, but cannot add value "HK" in the row.

Comment: so that i would like to know is my code error?

Comment: I think you may have used sqlBC.WriteToServer(Data) before updating row. just swich your code

Comment: @PrinceT Where can I put the code?